# "object name is already in use" while deploying custom metadata

Tags: deployment, metadata

I have custom object with API name channel__c. I am trying to deploy custom metadata with API name as channel__mdt.it is throwing an error of "object name is already in use".

Comment: The base name, ignoring the suffix, needs to be unique. You will notice the UI when creating/viewing these types include a name with no suffix.

Answer (score 0):

The error "object name is already in use" Shows that the API name of a custom metadata type is the same as the API name of an existing object, like a custom object, or standard object.

Here, the API name "channel__mdt" conflicts with the API name of the custom object "channel__c".

We cannot have two entities named the same.

To solve this issue, you can do any one of the following.

1. You can change the API name of the custom metadata type so that it will not create any conflict.
2. You can delete the custom object channel__c.

Once you solve the conflict, you can deploy without an error.